# ScrollViewer conflicts with Grid ColumnDefinition if content is too big

Tags: .net, wpf

This is more of a general question to figure out if this is intentional behavior or a bug in .NET

```xml
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Background="Green">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Violet" Opacity="0.7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Above XAML gives the following output:

[image]

What I discovered, is when on the Third Rectangle with the Violet Brush I set its Width to be larger than the Grid hosting the ScrollViewer, the Grid with the ColumnDefinitions resets its Column Behavior to be 1*:

[image]

The Designer still says that the first Column has a Width of 50px, but as you can see it's sharing the same total available space as the second Column, as if both were set to be 1*.

Is this intentional or actually a bug in .NET?

If it's the former, what would be the best approach to tackle this with only XAML to have the Columns behave the way they were defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is related to the `ScrollViewer`. `ScrollViewer` allows an infinite width, which obviously does not work well when measuring the spanning column width, where at least one column is dynamic (`*` or `Auto`).

`Grid` will always try to stretch to occupy the max available space if there is no constraint. In your first scenario, the parent `Grid` enforces such a constraint: when the child `Grid` measures itself, it gets the available size from the parent `Grid` (in your case [200,200]).

I this case, the child `Grid` can measure itself properly: the effective available space for the second column is

```
column_2_width = available_size_width - column_1_width = 200 - 50
```

In your second scenario, the `ScrollViewer`, which will become visible once the content exceed the viewport, will lift the constraint enforced by the parent `Grid` and provides an infinite space:

```
column_2_width = available_size_width - column_1_width = positive_infinity - 50
```

*positive infinity - x* is not defined. This becomes problematic for the spanning column width and `Grid` will now modify the `ColumnDefinition.Width` value. `Width`is just a desired value. It is not enforced or binding. To put a constraint on the width you can set the `ColumnDefinition.MinWidth` and `ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth` properties.

To ensure a specific fixed value (or final size), you should set all three properties `Width`, `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` to the same desired value.
This forces the layout system (out layout logic) to finally apply the desired value.

This why `FrameworkElement.ActualWidth` (actual value) deviates from the set `FrameworkElement.Width` (suggested value) in some cases.

All this applies to the `RowDefinition.Height` (or `FramworkElement.Height` in general) as well.

To fix the issue, you can assign a `ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth` to allow the `Grid` to measure itself correctly.

```xml
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Background="Green">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"
                                  MaxWidth="50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Violet" Opacity="0.7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

A fixed column width instead of a dynamic will of course also work.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I did end up using MaxWidth way before creating this post but felt like it was unnecessary since I already set fix boundaries, feel your answer is adequate enough and definitely helpful for whoever might stumble upon this same type of issue in the future.

Comment: Yes, Width does not define a fixed value, but a desired value. The layout system (in case of the Grid the relevant column calculations take place in the Arrange pass) will try to realize this desired dimension but the final value can alter within the range of MinValue and MaxValue. If those are not set, the final value is basically without any constraint. You will get away with the lack of min and max constraints most of the time. But there are some special cases you should definitely define them. Thank you very much!